Limit and DiscreteLimit seemingly missing some conditions
I'm trying to see what kind of parameters {a,b} lead to an existing limit of:
vNormal[t_, {a_, b_}] := 
 Exp[-(((-1 + b^t)  (2  a + Log[1 - 2 a]))/(2 (-1 + b)))]

So I use Limit like this:
In[122]:= Limit[vNormal[t, {a, b}], t -> \[Infinity], 
 Assumptions -> {b, a} \[Element] Reals, GenerateConditions -> True]

Out[122]= ConditionalExpression[E^((2 a + Log[1 - 2 a])/(2 (-1 + b))),
  2 a + Log[1 - 2 a] \[Element] Reals && 2 a + Log[1 - 2 a] != 0 && 
  Log[b] < 0]

Simplifying, I get this:
In[121]:= Reduce[
 2  a + Log[1 - 2  a] \[Element] Reals && 2  a + Log[1 - 2  a] != 0 &&
   Log[b] < 0, {a, b}, Reals]

Out[121]= (a < 0 || 0 < a < 1/2) && 0 < b < 1

So apparently, 0 < b < 1. However, limits also exist when -1 < b < 0:
In[126]:= 
Limit[vNormal[t, {0.3, #}], 
   t -> \[Infinity]] & /@ {-0.9, -0.7, -0.5, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1}

Out[126]= {1.0868, 1.09749, 1.11119, 1.12936, 1.14087, 1.15462}

Thus, the correct conditions seem to look roughly like (a < 1/2) && -1 < b < 1.

Did Mathematica miss the -1 < b condition? Am I missing something here? How do I ensure all conditions are generated?

The documentation does not state that GenerateConditions->True produces the sufficient and necessary conditions in all the cases. There is a nonempty set of the examples when only sufficient conditions are obtained.

Both you and Mathematica are right. The documentation does not state that GenerateConditions->True produces the sufficient and necessary conditions in all the cases. There is a nonempty set of the examples when only sufficient conditions are obtained. In the case under consideration for b <0 complex numbers are involved (think of b^t). The following works in 14.1 on Windows (It takes some time.).
Limit[ComplexExpand[Exp[-(((-1 + b^t) (2 a + Log[1 - 2 a]))/(2 (-1 + b)))]], 
t-> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> {a, b} \[Element] Reals,GenerateConditions -> True]


ConditionalExpression[Piecewise[ {{(1 - 2*a)^(1/(2*(-1 + b)))*E^(a/(-1 + b)),  b < 0 && 2*a <= 1 && 2*a + Log[1 - 2*a] != 0 &&  Log[-b] < 0}, {Infinity, b >= 0 && 2*a <= 1 &&  (-1 + b)*(4*a + Log[(1 - 2*a)^2]) < 0 && Log[b] > 0},  {0, b > 1 && 2*a > 1 && 4*a + Log[(1 - 2*a)^2] > 0 &&  Log[b] > 0}}, E^(a/(-1 + b))*Abs[1 - 2*a]^(1/(2*(-1 + b)))* (Cos[Pi/(2 - 2*b)] - I*Sin[Pi/(2 - 2*b)])],  (2*a <= 1 && ((Log[b] > 0 && b >= 0 &&  (-1 + b)*(4*a + Log[(1 - 2*a)^2]) < 0 && b != 1) ||  (b < 0 && Log[-b] < 0 && 2*a + Log[1 - 2*a] != 0))) ||  (2*a > 1 && ((b < 0 && Log[-b] < 0 &&  4*a + Log[(1 - 2*a)^2] != 0) ||  (b > 1 && 4*a + Log[(1 - 2*a)^2] > 0 && Log[b] > 0)))]

$$\fbox{$
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 (1-2 a)^{\frac{1}{2 (b-1)}} e^{\frac{a}{b-1}} & b<0\land 2
   a\leq 1\land 2 a+\log (1-2 a)\neq 0\land \log (-b)<0 \\
 \infty  & b\geq 0\land 2 a\leq 1\land (b-1) \left(4 a+\log
   \left((1-2 a)^2\right)\right)<0\land \log (b)>0 \\
 0 & b>1\land 2 a>1\land 4 a+\log \left((1-2 a)^2\right)>0\land
   \log (b)>0 \\
 e^{\frac{a}{b-1}} | 1-2 a| ^{\frac{1}{2 (b-1)}} \left(\cos
   \left(\frac{\pi }{2-2 b}\right)-i \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{2-2
   b}\right)\right) & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\text{ if }\text{condition}$} $$

If the limit as $t\to\infty$ exists, then the limit over positive integers (DiscreteLimit in MMA notation) exists too, The command DiscreteLimit[  ComplexExpand[   Exp[-(((-1 + b^t) (2 a + Log[1 - 2 a]))/(2 (-1 + b)))]],   t -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> {a, b} \[Element] Reals,   GenerateConditions -> True] results in

ConditionalExpression[Piecewise[  {{(1 - 2*a)^(1/(2*(-1 + b)))*E^(a/(-1 + b)),  b < 0 && 2*a <= 1 && 2*a + Log[1 - 2*a] != 0 &&  Log[-b] < 0}, {Infinity, b >= 0 && 2*a <= 1 &&  (-1 + b)*(4*a + Log[(1 - 2*a)^2]) < 0 && Log[b] > 0},  {0, b > 1 && 2*a > 1 && 4*a + Log[(1 - 2*a)^2] > 0 &&  Log[b] > 0}}, E^(a/(-1 + b))*Abs[1 - 2*a]^(1/(2*(-1 + b)))*  (Cos[Pi/(2 - 2*b)] - I*Sin[Pi/(2 - 2*b)])],  (2*a <= 1 && ((Log[b] > 0 && b >= 0 && (-1 + b)*(4*a + Log[(1 - 2*a)^2]) < 0 && b != 1) ||  (b < 0 && Log[-b] < 0 && 2*a + Log[1 - 2*a] != 0))) || (2*a > 1 && ((b < 0 && 

Log[-b] < 0 && 4*a + Log[(1 - 2*a)^2] != 0) ||  (b > 1 && 4*a + Log[(1 - 2*a)^2] > 0 && Log[b] > 0)))].

The outputs include the case $b>-1\wedge b<0$ : pay your attention to (b < 0 && Log[-b] < 0 && 2*a + Log[1 - 2*a] != 0))) ||  (2*a > 1 && ((b < 0 && Log[-b] < 0 &&  4*a + Log[(1 - 2*a)^2] != 0) in the conditional expressions.

Updated
If we absorb the terms in a as a constant:
a1 = Assuming[{b < 0, C[1] != 0}, 
   DiscreteLimit[Exp[-(b^t - 1) C[1]/(2 (b - 1))], t -> Infinity, 
    GenerateConditions -> True]];
r1 = Reduce[a1[[2]], b];
a2 = Assuming[{b > 0, C[1] != 0, C[1] \[Element] Reals}, 
   DiscreteLimit[Exp[-(b^t - 1) C[1]/(2 (b - 1))], t -> Infinity, 
    GenerateConditions -> True]];
r2 = Reduce[a2[[2]], b];
Reduce[r1 || r2, b]

then
(C[1] != 0 && -1 < b < 0) || 0 < b < 1

I tried a number of approaches and Mma at times produced contradictory conditions such -1<b<0 && 0<b<1. Other users may provide more insgiht.
Original answer
This is an extended comment. I admit to some difficulty parsing long conditional outputs. Mma  handles the limits numerically. As OP specifically comments on the cases for for $b<0$, as can be seen below DiscreteLimit is appropriate.
I think it is constructive to just breakdown the argument of the exponential.
Further, Mma has (perhaps understandable) difficulties returning results with some values.
In the following:

I manually try to provide insight into conditons

show some numerical examples

lend support to the conclusions that the discrete limit exists (-1,1). I tried to use Reduce to find where limit is finite but  failed. Others may have greater success.
p = Exp[-(((-1 + b^t)  (2  a + Log[1 - 2 a]))/(2 (-1 + b)))];
 Reduce[Im[Log[1 - 2 a]] == 0, a, Reals]
 Reduce[Im[b^t] == 0, {b, t}, Reals]
 f[u_, v_, s_] := p /. {a -> u, b -> v, t -> s}
 plt[u_] := Plot[DiscreteLimit[f[u, x, t], t -> Infinity], {x, -1, 1}]
 lmt[u_, x_] := DiscreteLimit[f[u, x, t], t -> Infinity]
 lmt[0.2, 3]
 lmt[0.2, -0.9]
 lmt[0.2, -1]
 lmt[0.2, -2]
 Grid[Partition[Table[plt[j], {j, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}}], 2]]



The output:

